# Return absolute icon image file path

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Is there a way to return the absolute icon image file path?

```
imagePath =  '/home/user/picture/image.jpg'

self.objectItem = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
self.objectItem.setText(folder)
self.objectItem.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(imagePath))
```

Later in the tool, I would like to access the QlistWidgetIte/icon current item and return the file path.

```
selectedItem = self.objectItem.currentItem()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path of the uploaded file to QIcon cannot be obtained since the QIcon only stores the data (image bytes). A possible solution in your case is to save the path in a role of the model:

```
imagePath =  '/home/user/picture/image.jpg'

objectItem = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
objectItem.setText(folder)
objectItem.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(imagePath))
objectItem.setData(QtCore.Qt.UserRole, imagePath)

your_qlistwidget.addItem(objectItem)
```

```
selectedItem = your_qlistwidget.currentItem()
imagePath = selectedItem.data(QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
```

Comment: Thank you! I completely forgot about user roles.